# How to Pass an array from Laravel Blade to a Vue Component in Laravel 6/Vue 2.6.*

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I am passing an object from my controller to my blade.php.file. From there I use object notation to get the variables from my object which leaves me with an array. I then am trying to pass that array of data from my blade.php file to my vue component. I want to pass the entire array not just one index of it. As of right now when I try to pass the array I get the error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` which makes sense because I am passing an array (which is what I want). How do I successfully pass an array of data from laravel blade to VUE?

blade.php file

```
<div id="app">
   <draggable
       draggable-table="{{ $table->vars }}">
    </draggable>
</div>
```

VUE component

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
       props: ['draggableTable'],
   };

</script>
```

EDIT:

As suggested to me I added a `:` and `json_encode` in my blade fole table like so:
`:draggable-table="{{json_encode($table->vars)}}">`
But when I check my VUE console my component no longer shows and only root is shown with none of the array data passed in. (See photo)

[image]

2ND EDIT:

I am trying to do this via axios now. I added this to my component within the `<script>` tags

```
 data(){
          return{
            table: this.draggableTable
          }
      },
       methods: {
          
          getData(){
              axios.get(this.endpoint, {
                 table: this.table,
              }).then(res => {
                 console.log(res);
              }).catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
              });
          }
       },

computed: {
          endpoint(){
             return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/users';
          }
      }
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

So now how to I pass the data from blade to VUE?

Thank you.

Comment: `<draggable :draggable-table="@json($table->vars)"></draggable>` should work.

Comment: @Remul I tried your solution as well but in my VUE browser console, only the root component appears with no data included.

Comment: can you share the app.js or where you crea vue instance please

Comment: @TEFO just posted it in my question

Comment: so you didnt register it locally in root instance. did you register this component globally?

Comment: @TEFO not sure what you mean. How do I register the component globally

Comment: Vue.component('draggable', { /* component staff */}) here: https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/Presets/vue-stubs/app.js#L22

Comment: NVM I did register it globally already

Comment: first have to get the component in this devtools more information needed e.x. plain html source or error logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218387/discussion-between-pa-gw-and-tefo).

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `:` in prop, live below code.

```
<div id="app">
   <draggable
       :draggable-table="{{ json_encode($table->vars) }}">
    </draggable>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it did not work for me. My data was not passed through to my component. I edited my question to include the details and a photo. Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a component load issue so could you please check why component is not loading.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your component is not loading.

Comment: So Using axios I was able to pass the data BUT it is coming through as a string of html, like this: “<div id=“users-table”><table>....table data here...</table></div>” and I am using the json_encode in my blade file. I want to pass the array not a string of HTML. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just send it as a JSON object and then parse it either in Vue or when accepting it as a prop.

```
<div id="app">
   <draggable
       :draggable-table=JSON.parse({{ json_encode($table) }})>
    </draggable>
</div>
```

Why would you need to pass data from Blade to Vue if you are using an API call in Vue? Data is already available to you.

Comment: I reverted my component to be simple and removed axios. It once again looks like it did in the original part of my question. So in my blade file I used your code snippet posted above to try to pass data from blade.php to VUE component but in my console I get this error: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

(found in <Root>), is your syntax correct?

Comment: What is the server returning? Does $table exist? What do you get when you just echo {{ json_encode($table) }}?

Comment: I am in a blade file so I have to @dd() $table but when I dd($table) I get back ComponentView {#1538 ▼
  +vars: array:38 [▶]
  +parent: null
  +children: []
  -rendered: true
}  If I add the json_encode, then when I dd($table) it returns false.

Comment: Just {{ json_encode($table) }} in your view. What do you get? And do you have laravel/telescope?

Comment: So I get a long string containing HTML. The html is the table I am trying to pass to VUE but It is going through as a string of HTML. ""<div class='box' data-plugin='true'><div id='users_table' class='users-style'><div....etc"

Comment: So you want to pass HTML to a Vue component from Blade. Not an array of data? Can you also post your controller to see what you are returning as $table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218529/discussion-between-pa-gw-and-arjun).